# What is the required .Net framework to work with API Gmail and VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, gmail-api

I am trying to integrate gmail-api into my Vb.Net application.
I want to know what is the required .NET framework version to use Gmail API.
Thank you.

```vb
Dim credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets With {.ClientId = strClientID, .ClientSecret = strClientSecret}, {GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify, GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly, GmailService.Scope.GmailSend}, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore("C:\token_json")).Result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*.NET Framework **Version 4.5.1.***

#### References:

- [Gmail API - .NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet)
- [Wikipedia - .NET Framerowk version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history)

#### Other Useful Links:

- [GMail API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/csharp/latest/)